# How to justify rows in a poem

Tags: css, text-alignment

I want to display poems in rows such that the ends of the rows are aligned, in order to emphasize the rhyming, like this:

```html
<div style='text-align:justify'>
<p>aaaa aaa aaaaaa aa aaa aaaa</p>  
<p>aaaa aaa aaaaa aaa aaaa aaaa</p>  
<p>aaa aaaa aaaa aaa aaaaa</p>  
<p>aa aaaaa aaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa</p>  
</div>
```

But this didn't work - most probably because each line is considered an individual paragraph.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: in line styles are a nono

Comment: I put my code above.

Comment: The title and the attempted code say “justify”, suggesting alignment on both left and right, achieved with increased spacing. But your description says “the ends of the rows are aligned”, suggesting right alignment only. Which one is it that you want?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I want both ends aligned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to use pseudo element `:after` to make `p` text not *the last* line of text, so that it will be justified properly:

```css
div {
    text-align: justify;
    background: #EEE;
    width: 200px;
}
div p:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <p>Ruculis merti asani.</p>
    <p>Tedrima ergi nihil et capet,</p>
    <p>Puritumus lasi ce lani.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to want to justify the lines on the left and on the right. This cannot be achieved in a simple way when the paragraphs are long, so that each line is the last line of its block and therefore does not get adjusted. There is an IE-specific property for setting the alignment of the last line and some proposed standard tools for the same, so far without browser support. So we need some tricks.

The issue is that *forced* line breaks, whether with `p` markup or `br` markup or with CSS, don’t play well with justification.

Here is one trick: Use markup where the lines are ended with `<br>`, no `p` markup. Set the poem as inline block, so that it will take its natural width (the width of the longest line). Then set its width to that value, with JavaScript, and also append a blank filler to each line, setting that filler to 100%, so that it causes a “natural” line break as far as justification is concerned. It also causes an empty line after the real one. This causes considerable vertical spacing, so set line height to half of the desired real line height, e.g. to 0.6 if you want 1.2 line height.

This an ugly hack, and I hope there is some better one...

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var poem = document.getElementById('poem');
  poem.style.width = poem.offsetWidth + 'px';
  poem.innerHTML = poem.innerHTML.replace(/<br>/g, 
    '<span class=fill></span>');                                          
}
```

```css
#poem {
  text-align: justify;
  background: yellow; /* just to show the block */
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0.6;
}
.fill {
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id=poem>
aaaa aaa aaaaaa aa aaa aaaa<br>  
aaaa aaa aaaaa aaa aaaa aaaa<br>  
aaa aaaa aaaa aaa aaaaa<br>  
aa aaaaa aaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa<br>
et finis coronat opus.<br>
</div>
```